# call queryPurchasesAsync without callback

Tags: android, kotlin, in-app-purchase, kotlin-coroutines

When using the code of [Android's billing sample app in Kotlin](https://github.com/android/play-billing-samples/tree/master/TrivialDriveKotlin) in my project I get compilation error. I'm not very familiar with Kotlin, but as I understand in the sample project the call was *somehow* converted to coroutine, however in my project it doesn't.

I don't know if that make sense, I compared the 2 projects and didn't find any hint what can cause this difference.

This is how the code looks like in my project:

[image]

Notice that it expects the second parameter and that the suspend keyword is marked as redundant. The same code compiles successfully in the sample project.

I found also the [following article](https://proandroiddev.com/google-play-billing-library-meets-kotlin-coroutine-c68e10553786) that talks about using Google Play Billing Library with Coroutine.
It doesn't give specific example of queryPurchasesAsync, but all other examples have suspendCoroutine block that doesn't exist in sample app.

Comment: According to the docs https://developer.android.com/reference/com/android/billingclient/api/BillingClient there is a `PurchasesResponseListener` as a second parameter in `queryPurchasesAsync` method. It seems the GitHub sources you use are outdated.

Comment: well, in that case why I don't get error in the sample project ? I verified I use the same version, and also when I check BillingClient in sample project there is a second parameter

Comment: Have you made sure that you added the kotlin version of the billing library to your dependencies? It should be `implementation "com.android.billingclient:billing-ktx:5.0.0"`

Comment: yes, that was it ! good catch ! I actually saw there were many differences between build.gradle of both projects, just wasn't sure which one is the relevant :) Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

as suggested by Adrian K, problem solved after adding missing Kotlin billing library